# Tutorial Recommendation in R: ML & Google Analytics?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, references

Just wondering if anybody has any suggestions as to a good introductory tutorial, that blends Google Analytics with a machine learning library.

I found [Mark Edmondson's](http://markedmondson.me/intro-to-machine-learning-with-web-analytics-random-forests-and-k-means/) one excellent. However, his guide envisages every user is logging in to use the website, which isn't really practical on this site, a blog. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.